# Open set as a countable union of spheres

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Could you tell me how to prove that each open set can  is a countable union of open balls: $ K\left( x,r \right) = \left\{ y  \in \mathbb{R} ^{n} | \ d(x,y) <r \right\}$ where d is the Euclid metric?

I know that  $U$ is an open set if $\ int \ U=U$

and for $E \subset \mathbb{R}, \ \ $ $intE=\bigcup \left\{K \ | \ K\subset E \ \right\} $ (K as defined above).

Comment: I think your terminology is rather unusual. What you call a sphere is usually know as an *open ball* and its boundary is what is conventionally known as spheres (in $\mathbb{R}^n$). Also, nowaday people call what you call a sum a *union*. Under the usual interpretation, no nonempty open set is a union of spheres.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker Your last sentence is wrong. Every open set is a union of spheres, you just need uncountably many of them. ;-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

$U$ is open, so for each $x \in U$, there exists $r > 0$ such that $K(x,r) \subset U$. Now you can find *rational* elements $p,q$ ($p \in \mathbb Q^n, q \in \mathbb Q$) such that $K(p,q) \subset K(x,r)$ and $x \in K(p,q)$.

This means that you can express $U$ as the union of such $K(p,q)$. And there are only countably many rational pairs $(p,q)$.

(This is basically the same as Pambos's answer, it just uses more words.)

Comment: Yes is basically the same but I like yours better (too) :)

Comment: @TonyK I guess I am pretty late but...do you know where I could find a proof that you can find rational elements with the conditions you wrote there?

Comment: @Analysis_Mark You can let p be a rational point in the ball K(x, r/3) and q be a rational number between r/3 and 2r/3. Then the ball K(p,q) contains x and is a subset of K(x,r).

Answer (score 5):

Prove that $U\cap \mathbb Q^n$ is dense in $U$.
 Then consider the family $\mathcal A =\left\{K(z,q):z\in U\cap \mathbb Q^n, q \in \mathbb Q,K(z,q)\subseteq U\right\}$.
Prove that $\mathcal A $ is countable and $\cup \mathcal A=U.$